# JQuery can't find my Element. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, jquery-selectors

**UPDATE: Silly me didn't notice that the CASE wasn't exact. I was struggling with this for 30+ minutes, and you guys saw my problem in less than 5!! thanks for saving me a lot of grief - I'm kind of new to programming anyway,I need to learn how to look out for little things like this, but thanks so much, it had not even crossed my mind:)**

**Sorry everyone - It was misleading before because I forgot to put quotes in my question, but I can assure you I know that the selector for Jquery requires quotes and I've been using them...**

```
<div id='question' style="background-color:#DAE2E8;border-color:#A2B3C7;border-width:1px;border-style:solid"><br /> 
    <table id='searchtable' border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="label">Question ID:</span><input id='QuestionId' type='text'/></td>
            <td><span class="label">Question Title:</span><input id='QuestionTitle' type='text'/></td>
            <td><span class="label">Original URL:</span><input id='OriginalURL' type='text'/></td>
            <td><span class="label">Original Title:</span><input id='OriginalTitle' type='text' /></td>
            <td><span class="label">Chronic ID:</span><input id='ChronicID' type='text' /></td>   
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="label">Expert Name:</span><input id='ExpertName' type='text'/></td>  
            <td><span class="label">Topic ID:</span><input id='TopicID' type='text'/></td>
            <td><span class="label">Channel ID:</span><input id='ChennelID' type='text''/></td>
            <td><span class="label">Funded: </span><input id='IsFunded' type='text'/></td>
            <td><span class="label">Funded Partner:</span><input id='FundedPartner' type='text'/></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='ApplyNewFilters(this)' /></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
</div>
```

So here is my HTML code (its in an aspx page) - I tried using `$("#QuestionID").val()` to get the value, but it won't work. I also tried `$("input#QuestionID").val()`.

Comment: Can you console.log the error?  Something should be returned if you try `console.log($("#QuestionID"));`

Comment: Not sure how to log the error. Right now it just tells me that it's undefined.

Comment: @gdoron I'm really new to JQuery. I come from a CSharp background so Javascript still is a whole other ballpark. Do you have any good resources on how to access/view the DOM and how to debug with Jquery

Comment: do you have any other element with QuestionId . check that too in your entire code

Comment: if `console.log($("#QuestionID"));` = `undefined`, then the error is that your javascript is running before `$("#QuestionID")` is available.  In other words, maybe, that input box is not on the screen when you javascript calling it runs?

Comment: Lol, just saw the answer and yeah, always remember to use exact casing. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using:

```
$("#QuestionId").val()
```

Note the quotes and exact case.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad6eJ/)

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post because i forgot to put the quotes in there in the first place. No that's definitely not the problem. I've been using quotes this whole time >< I've selected things before with the ID so I dont know whats going on

Comment: @user1274649 Note the case `QuestionID` and `QuestionId` - The `D`

Comment: Thanks, it was the Case. I will NEVER Make that mistake again!! I'm a Jquery novice so I wasn't sure if it was ME, or if I was using the wrong thing, or if it had to do with the html...thanks...a lot.

Comment: When in doubt, copy and paste the variable name. Even if it looks right, it's easy to make a mistake when you have stared at the screen for too long.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are using the correct case ?

`$("#QuestionId").val()` should work

If it is not working, go and check your firebug console tab to see whether there is some script error in the page

Comment: It wasn't the QUOTES, it was the CASE!! Whoa and I've been struggling with this goddamn thing for 30 minutes at least. Now I know I'll never make such an oversight again. Thanks so much for noticing :)

Answer (score 3):

the input id is QuestionId not QuestionID

Answer (score 2):

The selectors are case-sensitive, so you've mispelled the "Id"

```
$("#QuestionId").val()
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quote marks on your selectors.  It should be `$('#QuestionId').val()` or `$('input#QuestionId').val()`

Answer (score 1):

Try correcting the double quote at the line

```
<input id='ChennelID' type='text''/>
```

Answer (score 1):

look

```
<td><span class="label">Channel ID:</span><input id='ChennelID' type='text''/></td>
```

and this

```
<td><span class="label">Channel ID:</span><input id='ChennelID' type='text' /></td>
```

you have and extra ' at the end

in case you are using

```
<asp:TextBox />
```

you must create a var on javascript with the value of the asp client id

```
var ChannelID = <%=txtChannelID.ClientID %>
```

where clientid is the text box name